# Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView'

Tags: swift, tableview

[Code and errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZDss.png)
[Continued on the code and one more errors!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VjuN.png)

Hi, I'm new to Xcode swift. I have been doing good so far except trying to follow someone tutorial from 8.2 and I'm getting these errors that I have the hardest time understanding. Anybody who can explain what these errors means and maybe, just maybe how to fix them?

I have edited my posts, can't link more items than 2.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to declare your `tableView` up by your other `@IBOutlet`s since you are using a `UIViewController` and putting a `tableView` within it's view. Currently the `UIViewController` doesn't know what `tableView` you are referring too.

`@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!`

Then link it up in the interface builder as you have done with your other `@IBOutlet`s. Make sure you link the `delegate` and `dataSource` properties of your `tableView` back to the view controller as well.

To do the latter, after you select your `tableView`, select the Connections Inspector area, as shown in the picture below, and connect them back to your `UIViewController`.

[image]

Comment: Post updates in the comments here instead. Yeah seems like you have done it. Did you also connect your `@IBOutlet` reference to the `tableView`?

Comment: Yeah, I have done it, thanks a lot for the help! I need to keep my eyes open on the small stuff! =)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I've used:

```
@IBOutlet private weak var tableView: UITableView!
```

and use tableView inside extensions method.

I've change `private` to `fileprivate`, and error has gone.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is in Swift 4

```
let iPath = NSIndexPath(row: self.TableView.numberOfRows(inSection: 0)-1,
                        section: self.messageTableView.numberOfSections-1)

self.TableView.scrollToRow(at: iPath as IndexPath,
                           at: UITableViewScrollPosition.bottom,
                           animated: true)
```