# Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView' when dequeuing a cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm running into an odd error. This line of code functions correctly:

```
let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FeedCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell!
```

However when I cast to `FeedCell!` (a subclass of `UITableViewCell`):

```
let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FeedCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as FeedCell!
```

Xcode throws the error: `Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView'`

I'm not sure how it can be ambiguous, let alone triggered by a different casting!

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/a/33724276/5362916

Comment: I have checked this - but I'm using a subclass of UITableViewController rather than a UIViewController. Creating an IBOutlet named `tableView` just conflicts. 

In addition, why would that be triggered by me casting to a different cell subclass?

Comment: You're probably calling this method from a `UITableViewControllerDataSource` method that already takes `tableView` as a parameter. Try changing `self.tableView` to `tableView`.

Comment: Ismail's answer worked for me, oddly. I've removed the self so I'm referencing the `tableView` also. Thanks for all your advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing the line to

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FeedCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! FeedCell
```

Just remove the ! from `FeedCell!` and put it in `as!` and check if there is any difference.

Beside as @redent84 mentioned in his comment you should use `tableView` instead of `self.tableView`.

Comment: That actually worked! Why on earth did Xcode throw that other error, then?!

Comment: I'm not sure why the this error message. I just found the way you writing it is not right and suggested to change it and it might fix the weird error. Even if it didn't fix it, it worth to be changed anyway.