# Implement delegate method in Table View

Tags: swift, uitableview, delegates

I´have a table view with a custom cell. In this cell I have two buttons that are used for counting. One pluss button, and one minus button. These buttons should increment and decrease a counterLabel with 1.
I have done this in a project I did a long time ago, but then I used extensions, witch I don't do in this project. My problem is that I cannot figure out how to implement the delegate method that I used in the previous project.
I will show the code I'm trying, as an extension. This gives the error "Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)'".
How should I correctly implement the delegate?

Main View Controller
    import UIKit

```
    class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

        let staticList: [ListItem] =
        [
            ListItem(item1: "item1", item2: "item2", item3: "item3")]



        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
                return staticList.count
            }


        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

                let cell: UITableViewCell
                cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MenuCell", for: indexPath)

                if let customCell = cell as? MenuCell
                {
                    let itemIndex = indexPath.row
                    let listItem = staticList[itemIndex]

                    customCell.item1Label.text = listItem.item1
                    customCell.item2Label.text = listItem.item2
                    customCell.item3Label.text = listItem.item3
                    customCell.counterLabel.text = "\(listItem.count)"


                }
                return cell

            }
        }
        @IBOutlet weak var mainTableView: UITableView!
    }

    extension MainViewController: CountDelegate {
        func didAddItemCell(cell: MainCell) {
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)!

            staticList[indexPath.row].count += 1

            cell.countLabel.text = "\(staticList[indexPath.row].count)"
        }

        func didSubtractItemCell(cell: MenuCell) {
            let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)!

            if staticList[indexPath.row].count > 0 {
                staticList[indexPath.row].count -= 1

                cell.countLabel.text = "\(staticList[indexPath.row].count)"
            }
        }
    }
```

Table View Cell file

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

protocol CountDelegate: NSObjectProtocol {
    func didAddItemCell(cell: MainCell)
    func didSubtractItemCell(cell: MainCell)
}

class MenuCell : UITableViewCell
{

    @IBOutlet weak var item1Label: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var item2Label: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var item3Label: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var counterLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var minusButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var plusButton: UIButton!

    weak var delegate: CountDelegate?


    @IBAction func minusButton(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        delegate?.didAddItemCell(cell: self)

    }
    @IBAction func plusButton(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        delegate?.didSubtractItemCell(cell: self)

    }

}
```

Comment: Did you need to setup the delegate like this?: `class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate`

In addition, in your storyboard,  you must click and drag the tableview's delgate and datasource to your uiviewcontroller

Comment: I have  `class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate` It was somehow cut during editing. I also have clicked and dragged tableview's delgate and datasource to uiviewcontroller.

Comment: Hmm I dont think this will fix your error ... but to set up CountDelegate, you need to add `customCell.delegate = self`

Comment: Did you also link up the mainTableView IBOutlet in your storyboard? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33724190/ambiguous-reference-to-member-tableview

Comment: Yes! It was `customCell.delegate = self`after that I was made aware of a typo. Thank you!

Comment: Use callback closures. They are more reasonable in this case. No extra protocol, no setting of a delegate.

Answer (score 1):

The `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAt` methods are not part of the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol but the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol.  You therefore need to change add that protocol like this:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
```

You will also need to implement this as well:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1 // Or whatever it should be
}
```