# How to reset tableview cell contents from another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I must be missing something simple here. I have an app with multiple view controllers and I'm trying to reset tableview rows(specifically the `cell.detailTextLabel?.text`) when user navigates back in another viewcontroller

**SummaryViewController**

```
import UIKit

class SummaryViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, 
UITableViewDataSource {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    if isMovingFromParentViewController{
        allRecipeData.removeAll()
    }
}

let summaryStatementArr = ["Cell One", "Cell Two", "Cell Three", "Cell Four"]


var allRecipeData = [recipeSettings.recipeTimeSet, recipeSettings.selectedStirTimeArr.joined(separator: ", "), recipeSettings.recipeTimeSet, recipeSettings.recipeTimeSet]


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 4
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell4", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = summaryStatementArr[indexPath.row] 
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = allRecipeData[indexPath.row] // I want to reset this from firstviewController 
    return(cell)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

}
```

The elements in allRecipeData are declared in global variable using `struct recipeSettings{}`

I have another view controller that is linked to the one above called firstviewController

**firstviewController**

```
import UIKit

class firstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, 
UITableViewDataSource {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    // Code here to reset tableview cells in SummaryViewController
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) {
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) 
-> Int {
    return 7
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
-> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell3", for: 
indexPath)

cell.textLabel?.text = "Data"
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

}
```

How can I reset / reload / clear the tableview contents of SummaryViewController from the firstviewController. I hope its clear.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Assume you just wanna clear everything before moving to next view controller ? Or after moving you want to clear previous view controllers content ?

Comment: @ Gihan, Thanks for response, SummaryViewcontroller and firstviewController are connected by navigation controller. From SummaryViewController a user can click back and get navigated to firstviewController, from there, user can also click back and be navigated to another view controller. What Im trying to do is clear tableview in summaryviewController when user clicks back in firstviewController

Comment: if you clickBack in summaryviewController to firstViewController assuming you have push summaryviewController from firstViewController. Reference to summaryviewController get lost. So next time when you click again from firstViewController its a new summaryviewController. So you dont have to worry about it.

Comment: Please explain "push summaryviewController". At the moment whats happening is that when i click back from summaryviewcontroller and click back in firstviewcontroller then navigate forward to firstviewController then forward again to summaryViewcontroller, the values of `cell.detailTextLable?.text` remain unchanged

Comment: I will update the answer. seems like your pushing the same summaryviewController may be through seague.

Comment: check mu answer

Answer (score 0):

You could reload the tableView content when the view appears.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(animated)
tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: @ Mario Thanks for response, when I add that function to summaryViewController I get the error  "Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView" ?

Comment: @Darth do you hold a reference to the tableview?

Comment: @ Mario No I do not,Would i need to ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you clear things up before you leave the A -> B

See in your example you have hardcoded your data where as in a proper case you have to keep your data for cell in an array. This array should be able to set from outside of your delegates.

Assume you have and array called `dataArray` with 7 elements.

```
import UIKit

class SummaryViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, 
UITableViewDataSource {

var dataArray = ["data1","data2","data3","data4","data5","data6","data7"]
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    // Code here to reset tableview cells in SummaryViewController
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: 
IndexPath) {}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) 
-> Int {
    return dataArray.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) 
-> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell3", for: 
indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = dataArray[indexPath.row]
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

}
```

Now when you move to next view controller what you have to is

```
dataArray = []
tableView.reloadData()
```

If you wanna do this from the next class, you could keep reference from SummaryViewController and do the same. Don't forget proper keep of your view controllers for memory.

so in you summery class implement

```
func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    dataArray = []
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: @ Gihan Apologies had made an error in my example.There is no connection between `dataArray` in firstViewController class and `cell.detailTextLabel?.text` value in SummaryViewController class thus when i implement the solution it still remains unchanged

Comment: Just to be clear In firstViewController class within the `viewWillDisappear` function I would like to reset the tableview of SummaryViewController

Comment: there should be a array for data in each class. Or else how do you provide data to your tableview. Lets assume you wanna a have full hardcoded tableview and same value for cell.detailTextLabel?.text just dont had code it. set it through a variable and then change the value in the variable and rload

Comment: viewWillDisappear is in SummaryViewController not firstViewController. Infact all the code I have written is for SummaryViewController. you dont have to do anything in firstVIewController

Comment: Okay Ill change the value of `allRecipeData` as it is the array that populates the tableview but I still need to do it from firstViewController class because if user click back from summaryViewController class I need the tableview  to remain the same but if user click back from firstViewController thats when I need to reset the values

Comment: And also `tableView.reloadData()` is returning error "Ambiguous reference to member 'tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)" ?

Comment: what do you mean click back from firstViewController ? if you click back from firstViewController it should go to previous view controller. not summery. A->B->C click back from C is B. Click from B is A

Comment: Where do you define you tableView and its sources. check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33724190/ambiguous-reference-to-member-tableview.

Comment: If you are doing this for learning purposes or if you can share the project I can take a look.

Comment: From A->B->C if summaryviewController is C i want to be able to click back to B(firstViewController) with nothing changing in C but when I click back from B to A,  summaryViewController tableview will be reset. So in essence if i do navigate back to C the tableview will be reset.

Comment: Ok now I get it. Keep a reference of C in B. Call a method through that reference to reload table. Add  dataArray = []
    tableView.reloadData() to that method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reload your tableView in one Controller from another controller you should use delegate and protocol mechanism.

create a protocol

```
  protocol TableReloader {
     func reloadTable() 
  }
```

then confirm your first controller which contain the tableView:

```
  class ViewController1: TableReloader {
      func reloadTable() {
        self.tableView.reloadData() //instead of tableView use your table outlet's name
      }
  }
```

In secondViewController from where you want to reload this table take delegate:

```
  class ViewController2 {
      weak var delegate: TableReloader?
  }
```

while moving from ViewController1 to ViewController2 you need to give value to the delegate from ViewController1 as:

```
  let vc2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController2") as! ViewController2

  vc2.delegate = self // this is what I was saying to do.
  // now push or present
```

now in ViewController2 whenever you want to reload the tableView of ViewController1 just use:

```
  delegate?.reloadTable()
```

Thats all, hope it'll help you out